# Функция display_time

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал так, чтобы на экран, при нажатии кнопки, выводилось текущее время:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Вызов функции. Time()</title>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function display_time() {
      var now = new Date()
      var hours = now.getHours()
      var minutes = now.getMinutes()
      var seconds = now.getSeconds()
      var current_time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds
      document.write("Поточний час:" + current_time)
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name=orm1>
    Хотите узнать время?<br> Нажмите кнопку:<br>
    <input type=button value="Время" onClick="display_time()">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Как сделать, чтобы выводилась ещё и дата с новой строчки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<head>
  <title>Вызов функции. Time()</title>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function display_time() {
      let now = new Date();
      let time = {hour: 'numeric', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit'};
      let data = {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'};
      document.write(now.toLocaleTimeString('ru-RU', time));
      document.write('<br>');
      document.write(now.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU', data));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name=orm1>
    Хотите узнать время?<br>Нажмите кнопку:<br>
    <input type=button value="Время" onClick="display_time()">
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Очень благодарен